# Segmentation fault - accessing array elements passed from LLVM IR code

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I have a program that works fine when I run it using C++ however, when I call it from my LLVM IR code it does not work.

#### Function (library/library.cpp)

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT double *DOT(double A[3][3], double B[3][3]) {
  std::cout << A[0][0] << std::endl;
...
}
```

#### LLVM IR (out.ll)

```
declare [3 x double] @DOT([3 x [3 x double]], [3 x [3 x double]])
...
%a1 = load [3 x [3 x double]], [3 x [3 x double]]* %a
%b2 = load [3 x [3 x double]], [3 x [3 x double]]* %b
%calltmp = call [3 x double] @DOT([3 x [3 x double]] %a1, [3 x [3 x double]] %b2)
```

I did not include the full program to save space but, if it is useful just ask and I will update the question.

#### Error (built)

```
[1]    3086 segmentation fault  ./built
```

I use the following command to compile the code:

```
clang++ library/library.cpp out.ll -o built
```

#### Info

This works:

```
std::cout << A[0] << std::endl; // 0x1
```

This does not:

```
std::cout << A[0][0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your function with the wrong signature:

First, your function returns a pointer to double, not an array of doubles. This is pretty clear to see as the C++ code literally says `double *` as the return type.

The less obvious problem is that the types of your arguments are "pointer to array of double", not "array of array to double". This is because C and C++ do not support function parameters of array types, but decided, quite confusingly, to still accept the syntax for array types in parameter lists, but simply treat it as if it declared a pointer. So `double A[3][3]` in a parameter list (and only there) is just a more confusing way to write `double (*A)[3]`.

So in conclusion your declaration should be:

```
declare double* @DOT([3 x double]*, [3 x double]*)
```

Accordingly, you should also change your calling code to call `@DOT` with pointers of the right type.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful. What is the best way to get a pointer to array of doubles from and array of array of doubles using LLVM?

Comment: @pudility `getelementptr` with two zeros (assuming you actually start with a pointer to the array-of-arrays, which you would if it's in a variable).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that :)